# DirSyncRequestControl Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap

Implementing code (c#) to poll Active Directory for changes, however the line is throwing these errors, not quite sure what is wrong, thanks for any ideas.

1)"DirectorySynchronizationOptions' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySynchronizationOptions' and 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions"

2)Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySynchronizationOptions' to 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions'

also saying that there are invalid arguments

```
   DirSyncRequestControl dirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie, DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just try :

```
DirSyncRequestControl dirSyncRC = new DirSyncRequestControl(cookie,  System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectorySynchronizationOptions.IncrementalValues, Int32.MaxValue);
```

You can solve it in another way playing with `using`